# Macro to insert image filename into a cell

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I've used this code and I need some help to add two features:

1. Insert the pic name in a cell when picture selected
2. Create a link to a folder where this image followed by /picname.jpg

Is this possible?
Other thing is to use this in a range of cells
I've tried something like

```
  If Target = "$D$1:$D$10" Then
```

But don't works..

I would really appreciate some help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$1" Or Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Picture files (*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif), *.jpgs;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif", , _
"Select picture to insert")
        If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fName).Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = ActiveCell.Height
            .Width = ActiveCell.Width
            .Top = ActiveCell.Top
            .Left = ActiveCell.Left
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your picture filename variable is fName, and that you already have the path of your picture file as a variable also (let's assume it's called pName):

---

To insert the filename into a cell you could use (but are not limited to)

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value = fName
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = fName
```

---

To insert a link to the file, you could insert a hyperlink formula such as

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & pName & fName & "")"
```

---

As for the target, you could use an IF statement to ensure target is within the required range of cells:

```
 If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Row <= 10 Then

    '// Your code here

End If
```